# How to split a Guid List in to small part of lists

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I have a Guid List type of varchar(Max). This list has lots of Guid's which cross the sql limit.SO i have break this list in to small list as shown below.

```
 var sublists = customerList
               .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
               .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 2000)
               .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value.ToString()).ToList())
               .ToArray();
```

But this list is coming in char format as shown below.

[image]

I am not getting why this is coming in char format. Am I making any mistakes?

Comment: Because Select Method take each character from customerList string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `customerList` is a big string:

```
var sublists = customerList
    .Split(",")
    .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 2000)
    .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Is the same solution as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419063/1486443) but you must add `Split` Method first.

Comment: This is spltting smae way but sublist is not showing right output.If I have 3400 records in CustomerList then sublist should have index with (2000 and 1400 records).

Comment: If Customer List has 3400 list of Guid's.then It should be splits in 2 parts with index 0 and index 1.and index 0 should contain 2000 guids and index 1 should contain rest of guids.

Comment: Thanks. It was my mistake .Your previous solution was also right.And my problem is solved now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string[] sublists = customerList.Substring(0,2000).Split(',');
sublists = sublists.Take(sublists.Length - 1).ToArray();
```

That should give you the results you are looking for.

Comment: After doing this no changes in list

Comment: replace ToArray with ToList. if v.Value is a string, that should give you an object of type List<string>

Comment: What type is "Value"?

Comment: CustomerList is a Guid List which is coming like '''Guid'',''Guid'',''Guid'''

Comment: Ex :  customerList = @"'''70dd45f5-ac3f-4352-b8bd-cb5faad326bf'',''f5fc4992-fd77-498e-aa21-e1e963fc4e1f'',''be73ffdd-9c2a-42ae-b5e0-350945477eba''';

Comment: changed my answer for this data form

Comment: On split the compile time error is occurring.Split is not coming in intellisense.

Comment: Can you explain to me what you are trying to acomplish with this? .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 2000)

Comment: This is used for splitting full list with 2000 records of sublist.

Comment: If there is other solution for splitting a Guid list in to sublists then please tell me .I am stuck in this problem.